# Recursive Method with method call in the middle

Tags: java, recursion

I am practicing for my AP CSA exam tomorrow and have a question on a recursive method. Here is the method:

```
Consider the following recursive method.

public static void stars(int num)

{

if (num == 1)

{

return;

}

stars(num - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)

{

System.out.print("*");

}

System.out.println();

}

What is printed as a result of the method call stars(5) ?
```

I don't understand how to do this, as it seems to loop forever due to the stars(num-1) method call. Can someone explain line by line or step by step how to do this? I know the answer but not the reasoning. Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: load the code in an IDE and step through it in a debugger.  You can then see what it is doing.

Comment: The line `if (num == 1)` effectively controls how many levels deep the recursion can go (together with `stars(num - 1)`, where `num` is decremented). This descent happens before anything else - and it is why the recursion has a finite depth (and does not loop forever). From that point onward, you are climbing back up those levels (doing some star printing along the way, at each level) until you are back at the original level (and then you exit).

Comment: (Side note: some indentation would make your code a lot more readable in the question. Good luck tomorrow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call stars(5), first it'll check if its 1, since its not then it'll call starts(4), then stars(4) will call 3 and 3 will call 2 and 2 will call 1. You can think of it as the 5, 4, 3, and 2 methods are all waiting for the response of the stars() call that they made.

Once it is at 1, the method then will return, and subsequently give a response to stars(2), which then that method will continue from where it called stars(1) and print out **. Once the method ends it will once again send a response to 3 that it's done and continue the program until the 5th method has completed.

leaving you with:

**

***

****

*****